# Firebase Cloud Functions - Is there a way to remove/change metadata from a storage image upload

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Is there a simple, less intensive way of **deleting or changing Firebase Storage image metadata from cloud functions** without requiring Google Cloud Storage package downloading and re-uploading and replacing without metadata?

I can't find anywhere online or in docs.

Comment: To access Cloud Storage from within Cloud Functions, you use the Google Cloud Storage SDK for Node.js. It's hard to say if there is an easier way, without seeing what you currently do.